# shell script to bootstrap to multiple nodes with different ip address and name

Tags: shell-script

Hi i am trying to bootstrap to multiple nodes by passing ip file and name. below is my code

output: it should take ip from the ip.txt file and name from name.txt file

```
IP=`cat ip.txt`

USER="ubuntu"

KEY="test.pem"

NAME=`cat name.txt`

for ip in $IP; do

        knife bootstrap  $ip -ssh-port 22 --ssh-user $USER --sudo  --i $KEY --no-host-key-verify -N $NAME --run-list "role[webserver]"

  done

exit $?
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: If the script you wrote doesn't work, you should include the error message in your question.

Comment: I am actually trying to get the out put in below format by passing $IP and $NAME from two different files

1.1.1.1 web1

2.2.2.2 web2

3.3.3.3 web3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read ip.txt and names.txt into arrays 'ips' and 'names'. This assumes that
# the files have the same number of lines, and that both files are in the
# correct order (i.e. line N of ip.txt corresponds to line N of name.txt),
# so that the indices for both arrays match.
mapfile -t ips < ip.txt 
mapfile -t names < name.txt 

# Don't use all-caps variable names in your own scripts, they're probably already
# used by other programs.  $USER certainly is.  Use lowercase variable names.
user="ubuntu"
key="test.pem"

for i in "${!ips[@]}"; do
  knife bootstrap  "${ips[$i]}" -ssh-port 22 \
    --ssh-user "$user" --sudo  --i "$key" \
    --no-host-key-verify -N "${names[$i]}" --run-list "role[webserver]"
done
```

NOTE: `mapfile` is a `bash` built-in.  It's a synonym for `readarray`.

Also note: I don't run `chef` here, so I have no idea if your `knife bootstrap` command will do what you want.  I've assumed the syntax is correct and that you have used the appropriate options.

Comment: Thank you! I did modify as you recommended but running in to error;           ./test.sh ./test.sh: line 16: 34.206.64.216: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".206.64.216")

Comment: sorry, small typo.  change the `for i ...` line to `for i in "${!ips[@]}"; do` (note the `!` before `ips`) so that it iterates over the array indices rather than the array values.  I'll edit my answer.  Also added `-t` to `mapfile` commands to strip trailing newlines from the input files.

Comment: Awesome worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch! :)  Any good books to improve my knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

Using modern scripting in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
ip=$(< ip.txt)
user="ubuntu"
key="test.pem"
name=$(< name.txt)

for i in $ip; do
    knife bootstrap  $i -ssh-port 22 \
        --ssh-user $user --sudo  --i $key \
        --no-host-key-verify -N $name --run-list "role[webserver]"
 done
```

Not sure what is

```
"role[webserver]"
```

if it's a value from an associative array, then it should be written as

```
"${role[webserver]}"
```

Comment: it is creating a new node; Creating new node for weba1; Connecting to 34.200.65.216                                                                                                                                                                                 for the second node it connecting with same weba1 name but different ip address 52.34.65.12 ; Node weba1 exists, overwrite it? (Y/N) y                                                                                 
Client weba1 exists, overwrite it? (Y/N) y
Creating new client for weba1
Connecting to  52.34.65.12

Answer (score 0):

I am actually trying to get the out put in below format
by passing $IP and $NAME from two different files

1.1.1.1  web1

2.2.2.2  web2

3.3.3.3  web3